# Output with Python Glob // Cannot find where is error in Python code

Tags: python, output, glob

I have the following code, which does NOT give an error but it also does not produce an output.

The script is made to do the following:

- The script takes an input file of 4 tab-separated columns:
- It then counts the unique values in Column 1 and the frequency of corresponding values in Column 4 (which contains 2 different tags: C and D).
- The output is 3 tab-separated columns containing the unique values of column 1 and their corresponding frequency of values in Column 4: Column 2 has the frequency of the string in Column 1 that corresponds with Tag C and Column 3 has the frequency of the string in Column 1 that corresponds with Tag D.

Here is a sample of input:

```
algorithm-n   like-1-resonator-n   8.1848   C
algorithm-n   produce-hull-n   7.9104   C
algorithm-n   like-1-resonator-n   8.1848   D
algorithm-n   produce-hull-n   7.9104   D
anything-n   about-1-Zulus-n   7.3731   C
anything-n   above-shortage-n   6.0142   C
anything-n   above-1-gig-n   5.8967   C
anything-n   above-1-magnification-n   7.8973   C
anything-n   after-1-memory-n   2.5866   C
```

and here is a sample of the desired output:

```
algorithm-n   2   2
anything-n      5   0
```

The code I am using is the following (which one will see takes into consideration all suggestions from the comments):

```
from collections import defaultdict, Counter 


def sortAndCount(opened_file):
    lemma_sense_freqs = defaultdict(Counter)    
    for line in opened_file:
        lemma, _, _, senseCode = line.split()
        lemma_sense_freqs[lemma][senseCode] += 1
    return lemma_sense_freqs

def writeOutCsv(output_file, input_dict):
    with open(output_file, "wb") as outfile:
        for lemma in input_dict.keys():
            for senseCode in input_dict[lemma].keys():
                outstring = "\t".join([lemma, senseCode,\
                str(input_dict[lemma][senseCode])])
                outfile.write(outstring + "\n")

import os
import glob


folderPath = "Python_Counter" # declare here

for input_file in glob.glob(os.path.join(folderPath, 'out_')):
    with open(input_file, "rb") as opened_file:
        lemma_sense_freqs = sortAndCount(input_file)
    output_file = "count_*.csv"
    writeOutCsv(output_file, lemma_sense_freqs)
```

My intuition is the problem is coming from the "glob" function.
But, as I said before: the code itself DOES NOT give me an error -- but it doesn't seem to produce an output either.

Can someone help?

I have referred to the documentation [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html) and [here](http://www.thomas-cokelaer.info/tutorials/python/module_glob.html), and I cannot seem to understand what I am doing wrong.

Can someone provide me insight on how to solve the problem by outputting the results from `glob`. As I have a large amount of files I need to process.

Comment: `glob()` expands *existing* filenames. That is working just fine. But the `output_file` string will *not* be expanded for you; use string formatting or concatenation to generate a filename instead.

Comment: However, that is not your problem here; you have a name error on `lemma_sense_freqs`; that is a local name in the function `sortAndCount`, which you never call.

Comment: When I use as input one individual file, it seems to work just fine. `with open("out_ABC", "rb") as opened_file:` `lemma_sense_freqs = sortAndCount(opened_file)`
`output_file = "count.out_ABC.csv"`
`writeOutCsv(output_file, lemma_sense_freqs)`

Comment: And how did you define `lemma_sense_freqs` in that case?

Comment: @MartijnPieters please refer to revised question.

Comment: **Exactly**. Look at the line `lemma_sense_ferqs = sortAndCount(opened_file)`. Where is that line in your other code? Read the exception carefully, what does it tell you is missing?

Comment: I read your exception, I am not an expert Martijn Pieters, which is why I am asking for help. I have revised my code as to your suggestion and it still gives me an error. The updated codes is the following: 
`folderPath = "Python_Counter"` # declare here

`for input_file in glob.glob(os.path.join(folderPath, 'out_*')):`
    #print input_file
    `with open("out_*", "rb") as opened_file:`
    `lemma_sense_freqs = sortAndCount(opened_file)`
    
`output_file = "count*"`
`writeOutCsv(output_file, lemma_sense_freqs)`

Comment: Sorry, no, I won't continue this in chat; I don't have that much time at the moment. Update your question instead.

Comment: when you say "However, it is still giving me an error." which is exactly the error?

Comment: please see revised question @Albz

Comment: well, in the latest code that doesn't give any error try to change     `folderPath = "/Desktop/Python_Counter"` with `folderPath = "/Desktop/Python_Counter/*"`

Comment: Yes, I did. Still nothing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In regards to your original code, *lemma_sense_freqs* is not defined cause it should be returned by the function *sortAndCount()*. And you never call that function.
For instance, you have a second function in your code, which is called *writeOutCsv*. You define it, and then you actually call it on the last line.

While you never call the function *sortAndCount()* (which is the one that should return the value of *lemma_sense_freqs*). Hence, the error.

I don't know what you want to achieve exactly with that code, but you definitely need to write at a certain point (try before the last line) something like this

```
lemma_sense_freqs = sortAndCount(input_file)
```

this is the way you call the function you need and lemma_sense_freqs will then have a value associated and you shouldn't get the error.

I cannot be more specific cause it is not clear exactly what you want to achieve with that code. However, you just are experiencing a basic issue at the moment (you defined a function but never used it to retrieve the value lemma_sense_freqs). Try to add the piece of code I suggest and play with it.

Comment: Thank you for your kind response Albz. I followed your instructions, and now I do not receive any error - as I have indicated in my revised question. However, nothing happens - no error, no output.